# Separate conditional statements with | operand

Tags: python, pandas, operands

I am trying to produce a dataframe with these two conditional statements. I am using the | operand or the 'or' operand to separate the conditional statements. There is not an issue with the conditional statements because when I run them separately they work fine. Is there any other way I can separate these conditional statements?

My code:

```
df = df2[(df2['TABNo'] == 0) & ~df2['IsBarrierTrial']] | df2[(df2['Position'] == 0)]
print(df)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'bool'
```

Comment: What are you hoping a bitwise OR would do when applied to a bool and a float?

Comment: What's your expected output for writing `df1 | df2`?

Comment: I would like to seperate the conditional statements ... that is all. Why can I apply an '&' to first conditional statement if it is a bool and float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reindenting your statement:

```
df = (
    df2[
        (df2["TABNo"] == 0)
        & ~df2["IsBarrierTrial"]
    ]
    | df2[(df2["Position"] == 0)]
)
```

It looks like you're really looking for

```
df = df2[
    (df2["TABNo"] == 0)
    & (~df2["IsBarrierTrial"])
    | (df2["Position"] == 0)
]
```

to select a bunch of items instead of having that one nested `df2` indexing.

Answer (score -3):

Use `or` / `and` instead of `&` / `|` and check if error is resolved.